# How do i divide a pandas dataframe into multiple smaller dataframes or lists of tuples?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i am reading in a large csv file to memory with pandas.read_csv(path, low_memory=False)
I want to extract certain groups of rows line by line and insert them into a database.
I know that rows 11 to 62 go into one table and rows 65 to 10000 go into another table
is there a way to grab a subset of rows from the dataframe to loop over seperately. I also need to only process data in the subset if element 2 of the row is not nan.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of solutions for your problem. From the [pandas read_csv documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

**skiprows**

> ```
> Line numbers to skip (0-indexed) or number of 
> lines to skip (int) at the start of the file.
>
> If callable, the callable function will be evaluated against the row indices, 
> returning True if the row should be skipped and False
> otherwise. An example of a valid callable argument would be lambda x:
> x in [0, 2].
> ```

**skipfooter**

> ```
> Number of lines at bottom of file to skip (Unsupported with engine=’c’).
> ```

**nrows**

> ```
> Number of rows of file to read. Useful for reading pieces of large files.
> ```

The most intuitive solution for you would be

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(path, low_memory=False, skiprows=65, nrows=10000-65)
```

But of course you could also go for

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(path, low_memory=False, skiprows=65, skipfooter=total_rows-10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
dataframe_name['column_name'] (conditions) (value)
```

Example:

```
dataframe['row_num'] > 200
```